# Replace each nth character with "_"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a coding problem and it seems my thinking process is wrong in this problem. I'm trying to solve the following:

```js
/*
        Given a string and a number n, replace every nth character with '_'.
        "foreigner", 2 => "f_r_i_n_r"
        "leetcode", 3 => "le_tc_de"
        "leetcode", 1 => "________"
        */
function replaceChar(string1, number) {
  let stringArr = string1.split("")
  for (let i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
    if (i === i + 1) {
      stringArr[i] = "_"
    }
  }
  stringArr.join('')
  console.log(stringArr)
}
replaceChar("foreigner", 2);
```

The function at bottom is written by me and it seems it's not working as I intended.

Comment: "not working as I intended" is not a sufficiently detailed description of what happens.  Perhaps describe expected vs actual results, or list any error messages that you got.

Comment: You forgot to use the `number` parameter.

Comment: `i === i + 1`,  is `false` for every value except +/- Infinity. (Well, in practice some really big floating point numbers too)

Comment: Hint.  Determine if `i + 1` is divisible by `number`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Comment: `for (let i = number-1; i < stringArr.length; i=i+number) { stringArr[i] = "_" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the funcion almost right, except for the `if (i === i + 1)` condition…

You need to check if the remainder of `(i + 1 / number)` is `0`:

```
function replaceChar(string1, number) {
  let stringArr = string1.split("")
  for (let i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) % number === 0) {
      stringArr[i] = "_"
    }
  }
  console.log(stringArr)
  // or: return stringArr.join('')?

}
replaceChar("foreigner", 2);
```

BTW As other pointed out, the `stringArr.join('')` is not doing anything – you probably need to assign it to a variable and return it (or return it directly – as proposed in the code).

Comment: Well... `stringArr.join("")` doesn't magically change the array into a string. You've got to assign the result to something else (maybe itself?).

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I've missed that. Edited the answer…

Comment: Thank you. I had trouble in figuring out what to put in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

[GrafiCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5334486/graficode)'s suggestion in the comments is another interesting solution:

```js
/*
  Given a string and a number n, replace every nth character with '_'.
  "foreigner", 2 => "f_r_i_n_r"
  "leetcode", 3 => "le_tc_de"
  "leetcode", 1 => "________"
*/
function replaceChar(string1, number) {
  let stringArr = string1.split("");

  for (let i = number - 1; i < stringArr.length; i = i + number) {
    stringArr[i] = "_";
  }

  return stringArr.join("");
}

console.log(replaceChar("foreigner", 2));
console.log(replaceChar("leetcode", 3));
console.log(replaceChar("leetcode", 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides other answers, you may use Regex too:

```js
function replaceChar(string1, number) {
  let regex = new RegExp(`([a-z]{${number-1}})[[a-z]{1}`, 'ig');
  
  return string1.replace(regex, (a, b) => b + '_') 
}

console.log(replaceChar("foreigner", 2));
console.log(replaceChar("leetcode", 3));
console.log(replaceChar("leetcode", 1));
```